Report Builder Drawing Image code does not execute when connected to SSRS Server
I have been working on a report in Microsoft Report Builder that will display barcodes based on an id number I am pulling from one of our databases. I followed the answer that was submitted here and I can kinda get it to work.
So I added my Data Source (Database Server that hosts the Database I am pulling the ID from), added my Dataset that has the ID value, and then followed the steps in the link above. While doing this I never connected to our Report Server that hosts the reporting services (however I am actually creating the report on that server). When I finished following the steps in the link, I was getting proper barcodes appearing in the report.
However once I uploaded the report to our Reporting Server (SSRS version 15.0.1102.861) it no longer displayed the Barcodes, that image was just blank. This also happens in Report Builder if I connect to the Report Server before running the Report.
I will note again that I create the reports in Report Builder running on the Report Server that hosts the SSRS services. When I click to connect to the Report Server in Report Builder I enter in the Report Server Web Service URL we setup in the configuration Manager. I'm assuming when connected like this the report is running the same way it will run when it used through the web interface for our SSRS reports.
My only guess is that when it is running this way it no longer has access or can find the references to the System.Drawing dll. Because of that nothing is able to be drawn.
Hopefully all that makes sense, but I can always try and give more details if needed. Thank you for any and all of your help.
